# Initialize struct with (shadowed) base-class data members in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, initialization, shadowing

It's possible to add members to a derived `struct` that *shadow* same-name members of the base class, whether this is an error or not is addressed by [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40908402/2932052). My question is about initializing hidden inherited members. By-value assignment of derived `D` to base class `B` is permitted by the is-a relationship, but it's hard to *initialize* the inherited member that corresponds to the base class. In the following example, initialization is done with a brace-enclosed initializer list for `B` but this is not possible for `D`. The only option I found for getting defined `D` instances was to default-initialize (zero) and assign afterwards:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct B { int x; };
    struct D: B { int x; };
    B bas = {1};
    cout << bas.x << endl;
    D der = {};
    der.x = 2;
    bas = der;
    cout << bas.x << endl;
    der.B::x = 3;
    bas = der;
    cout << bas.x << endl;
    static_cast<B&>(der).x = 4;
    bas = der;
    cout << bas.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1
0
3
4
```

The following ideas, which I assumed might work, resulted in compiler errors:

```cpp
    D der = {1, 2};
```

> error: could not convert '{1, 2}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'main()::D'

```cpp
    D der = {B::x=1, 2};
```

> error: invalid use of non-static data member 'main()::B::x'

> error: could not convert '{<expression error>, 2}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'main()::D'

(`g++.exe -Weffc++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -std=gnu++11 -std=c++11 -fexceptions -g -std=c++11` with gcc 8.1.0)

Is there a way for proper initialization in C++11?

**Addendum:** 
When I asked this question, I was so focused on the difficulties to access shadowed members that I totally missed the limited options for [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) in C++11. So answers to this question will also apply to derived classes without hidden data members.

Comment: Add a `D` constructor taking two arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D der = {1, 2}` would work in C++17, as

```
D der = {{42}, 2};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aad0ff1fe209fc6)

For previous version, you cannot initialize base like that and you need a constructor.

Comment: I see, do you maybe have a reference link? I'm a bit lost and only found [*Zero initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) so far.

Comment: Look at [aggregate_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). aggregate definition changed. (in particular in respect to public base classes).